# requests library: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: php, python-3.x, apache, python-requests

I have a python script which uses requests library to connect to a device with its web-interface. It uses a url with https connection.

```
sess = requests.Session()
try:
          resp = sess.post('https://' + device + '/url_admin/login.cgi', data=login_data, verify=False)
except Exception as e:
            template = "Exception: {0}\nArguments: {1!r}"
            print(template.format(type(e).__name__, e.args))
```

When I try to execute it from command line it works perfectly (even with apache user). However, when it is triggered with a php code (exec function) from a web-portal. it throws this error

```
Exception: ConnectionError
Arguments: (MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='some.device.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /url_admin/login.cgi (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f55aa8e6550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 13] Permission denied',))",),)
```

I am not sure what is the reason because the apache user is able to execute it and make connection. Why it is not connecting when executed by php code?

Answer (score 5):

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on

Comment: You are a LIFESAVER. Thank you