# HTTPConnectionPool: Max retries exceeded Caused by NewConnectionError: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-requests

Hi I'm trying to get REST request from a certain URL and if I input the url directly in the browser it works ok and output is as show in the image below

[image: rest request via browser]

If I also try to query the url via native python on the same server where my django app is and it works fine too.

[image: rest requests via python]

The problem is when i put the request in view.py in my django project I get a connection error as the the title of this question.

```
import requests

def my_method(request):
    response = requests.get('http://10.150.20.103:8000/se/se-seid')
    special_events_dashboard_events = response.json()
    for event in special_events_dashboard_events['events']:
        context['special_events'].append(event)

    return render(request, 'updates/updates_network.html', context)
```

When I check the page in the browser, I get this error.

[image: django error]

The **REST API url** is of **different IP Address** from my django application.

Is this a setting problem in my django application? How to work around this? I have been searching in the internet but I cant seem to find an answer to this.

Comment: Are you sure your django application is able to even see the API? Does the API block requests without certain headers? Is the API behind a firewall...?

Comment: @goalie actually thats something im not sure and apparently it seems like my django app cant connect to it. What makes me wonder is that when i try vanilla python on the same server where my django app is as show in the 2nd image above, it can access the api with no additional headers.

Comment: @JCm you are trying to call Django URL within the same Django project ???

Comment: @c.grey no sir, the url where im requesting the data is a different django project that is also on a different server.

Comment: @JCm is this Django **http://10.150.20.103:8000/se/se-seid**

Comment: @c.grey Yes its also a django app

Comment: Im thinking its related to django x-site forgery security setting

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the problem here. It turns out its not django that is causing the problem rather its the Selinux settings of the server where my django project is deployed.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52528590/requests-library-failed-to-establish-a-new-connection-errno-13-permission-de) similar permission error problem here, where the solutions states to enable httpd_can_network_connect context. After setting the context to **ON**, i can now connect to the api url.